# My HTML file won't link with my Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to complete an exercise for one of my courses and my HTML file won't link with my Javascript file. I put the link between my HTML file and my Javascript file in the body of my HTML file but the files still won't connect. When I test this code in Microsoft Edge, the buttons simply do not work. Anybody know what the problem is?

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
        <head>
            <title>HTML Page</title>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <button onclick = "startWorker()">Start Worker</button>
            <button onclick = "stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>
            <ul id = "output">      
            </ul>
            <script type = "text/javascript" src = "/js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var worker;
function startWorker(){
    worker = new Worker ("js/mod4_worker.js");
    worker.onmessage = function(event){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += '<li>' + event.data + '</li>';
    };
}
function stopWorker(){
    worker.terminate();
}
```

[image: Directory Structure]

[Files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jmc44utubg8pqm/Workers%20and%20Buttons.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: Looks like you'll probably need `"/js/mod4_worker.js"` in that string. What is the address in your browser that loads your HTML file?

Comment: Try a relative path "../js/script.js". Otherwise, give us the URL of the HTML file and JS file. The worker JS file path is maybe not good too. Hard to say without the URLs. Is this the real file structure we see there ? @Phil A worker loads a JS file, no need to add it in the page.

Comment: These errors are showed on button click or on page loading ?

Comment: Errors are shown because of button click.

Comment: So the problem is clearly the path of the JS script "script.js"

Comment: The script.js and mod4_worker.js resides in the same folder, so you can just call "mod4_worker.js"

Comment: Remember that if you open an HTML file without a web server(with the root path on your project) using a path like `file://D:\foo\bar\index.html`, `/js/script.js` will refer to `file://D:\js\script.js`

Comment: @MasterDJon I meant in the `script.js` where OP currently has `new Worker ("js/mod4_worker.js");`

Comment: @Adrian no, that's not how it works. Relative paths are relative to the document, not the script

Comment: @Phil Ah ok ! No offence.

Comment: Try to change `<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/js/script.js"></script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>`

Comment: @GGG Already have done it. Unfortunately, changing it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @TheZombieCloud Could you post a picture of the source in the browser then? The output in the network tab makes no sense.

Comment: @GGG Source Posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I would try my comments :

- Change the script.js path to : "../js/script.js"
- Change the worker passed script to "../js/mod4_worker.js"

As GGG said, using a path starting with "/", a slash, use the path from root. The full path is either :

- Windows : file://DriveLetter:\REST_OF_PATH
- Unix/Linux/OSX : file:///REST_OF_PATH
- WebServer : http://domain/REST_OF_PATH

If the structure is from /webapp/ :

- html/index.html
- js/script.js

Accessing script.js from index.html needs to go back one folder (..) and then set the path seen here (js/script.js) which gives (../js/script.js) OR using full path (/webapp/js/script.js) which I wouldn't recommend because if you change "webapp" directory of location or URL (on WebServer)

Comment: The changes make the files much easier to read. It does not solve the problem though. Anyway, thanks for the tips.

Comment: In the browser, in dev tools, in the network tab (reload if you see nothing), is the script.js file there (it should) ? Is the file gives a 404 error ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please which include the address bar and this network tab ?

Comment: Posted the screenshot of address bar and dev tools.

Comment: OK, can you add a screenshot of "View source" ? This seems no sense.

Comment: The View Source is posted.

Comment: Can you zip the whole project and post it ?

Comment: Zipped the project and posted it on Dropbox.

Comment: Finally, I wasn't sure about the worker script path. It has to be : "../js/mod4_worker.js". And with that, it works properly with Edge directly on my computer. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the / from your src in the index.html. So it should be

```
src = "js/script.js"
```

Why? When you begin the src value with a /, that means you're referring to an absolute path (in other words, it starts the path from your drive's root). My devtools shows it as

```
file:///C:/js/script.js
```

By removing the first / in your src, you're now doing relative pathing, and it will look in the correct place.

Comment: Removing the "/" will search for a "js" file in the "HOMEWORK" folder. "js" file is outside of it. Thanks for the tips though.

Answer (score 0):

## Permissions & File locations

*(Stumbled on this Q and here's the only way I solved it...)*

For me, I found it was a permissions and file location issue...

I'm running a local webserver on Ubuntu 18 Desktop, working with dev from a local folder linked to the web directory: `/var/www/html/MY_DEV -> /home/me/MY_DEV`. So, the `www-data` user couldn't actually "own" them like it needed to.

I use this setup just fine for PHP, HTML, and CSS just fine. But, if I include a javascript file via `src=""`, no matter what I do, it doesn't work.

The only way I could get it to work on my desktop is if BOTH the served file (`somefile.php` or `somefile.html`) are physically at `/var/www/html/...`

And, of course accessing them at `localhost/...`

And, of course owning them obsessively with `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html`